# Mojolicious session destructor

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How can I call some custom action, when a session of a user expires. Can this be done with mojolicious? Can it be done with other web frameworks?

What is the term I am looking for, I don't know what to google, except "session destructor" or "session destroy".

Specifically I want to notify an external API, deleting the session there.

Comment: I don't know how that works in mojo, but in Dancer2 you could write your own session, subclassing whatever type of session you want to use, and overwrite or wrap the `_destroy` method to sign out of your API. See https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Role::SessionFactory#destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not getting any answers on your question, I decided do some digging.

I found [Plack::Session::Cleanup](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Session::Cleanup) (which can be used by [Plack::Middleware::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::Session)) that seems to have what you wish.  Unfortunately, here's where I ran into problems, there's a [MojoX::Session::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::Session) for [Plack::Middleware::Session::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/MojoX::Session::Simple), but no connectors for the non-Simple modules.  So, I don't know if this will help you, but you might poke around and see if it can.

---

I then looked at `Mojolicious::Sessions`, `Mojolicious::Sessions::Storable`, `MojoX::Session` and `Mojolicious::Plugin::SimpleSession` to see how they handle expiration...

Looking at [the code for `Mojolicious::Sessions`](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-6.11/lib/Mojolicious/Sessions.pm), it seems that the sessions are only stored within the cookie and the expiration is only checked when the cookie is loaded back from the client.  If you had a hook at line 24 to handle the expired session, it might get called multiple times for the same expired session (and probably not what you want) or it may never get called (if the client stops accessing the system before expiration).

`Mojolicious::Sessions::Storable` is based on `Mojolicious::Sessions` and seems to have the same expiration code (with the same issues).

Looking at [the code for `MojoX::Session`](https://metacpan.org/source/VTI/MojoX-Session-0.33/lib/MojoX/Session.pm), it looks like `flush` has a provision for a callback (for both previously expired sessions at line 216 and newly expired sessions at lines 227, 233, 262 and 268 [unfortunately there's no way to distinguish between the two]).  *Unfortunately, this functionality is not documented and so it might go away at any time plus I'm not sure when/how it can be used (again because it isn't documented).*

`Mojolicious::Plugin::SimpleSession` has a single method (`_too_old`) that could be overridden.

I also looked at `WWW::Session::Storage::File` which is often used with `WWW::Session` which can be used via `Mojolicious::Plugin::WWWSession` and you could put a hook [in the code](https://metacpan.org/source/HOREA/WWW-Session-0.12/lib/WWW/Session/Storage/File.pm) around line 112, but again nothing is built-in.

So, in summary, the *undocumented* callback in `MojoX::Session`'s `flush` method comes closest, but all of these solutions have one fatal flaw: **they only get called when a transaction happens** and this means that you'll miss some expirations (unless you have another mechanism to handle those).  Because of this, I think it is best that you have the other API manage its session cleanup based on a longer timeout then your application's session or create your own timeout/cleanup mechanism for the other API's session stored in your application.

Comment: So it seems there is no direct answer to my question allowing me to do that in Mojolicious. Anyway now I have a lot of pointers where to do more research. Thanks

Comment: It seems that "`Mojo::Server::PSGI` allows Mojolicious applications to run on all PSGI compatible servers", but I wouldn't know if you can use `Plack::Middleware::Session` and `Plack::Session::Cleanup` with it nor how to and if it is worth it.  Good Luck.  If you find a solution, please come back and answer your own question!

Comment: I just noticed `Mojolicious::Plugin::PlackMiddleware` which should allow you to use `Plack::Middleware::Session` and `Plack::Session::Cleanup` from Mojolicious.  I don't know if it works, but it is worth checking out!